# Is there a change log for DRCSIM 2.7.0 (and updated roadmap)?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Where can I find a change log for drcsim 2.7.0?

Related:  Can you update the roadmap on the wiki?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4171/is-there-a-change-log-for-drcsim-2.7.0-(and-updated-roadmap)?/) by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 298 on 2013-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Updated [DRCSim RoadMap](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Roadmap) and [DRCSim 2.7.x ChangeLog](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Change_log#drcsim_2.7.x).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0